# Use laws of set theory to show equality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

We have sets $X,Y,Z$. By laws of set theory we are to show that $$(X∪Y∪Z)\triangle(X∩Z∩Z)=(X∪Y∪Z)\backslash(X∩Z∩Z),$$
where $\triangle$ denotes symmetric difference.

I started by using the following identity for sets $A, B$:
$$A\triangle B=(A-B)∪(B-A)$$

By applying this to our case, the left side of the equation yields
$$(X∪Y∪Z)∪(X∩Z∩Z)-(X∪Y∪Z)∩(X∪Y∪Z).$$

By then applying the absorbation law, this can be rewritten as
$$(X∪Y∪Z) - (X∩Z∩Z),$$
given that I haven't made any mistakes. From my understanding this equals $(X∪Y∪Z)\backslash(X∩Z∩Z)$, which we were supposed to show.
The problem is from a discrete mathematics class and since we haven't really covered symmetric difference, I would appreciate some input.

Comment: (X∩Z∩Z) is a subset of (X∪Y∪Z) so a symmetric difference equals asymmetic one in this case. Just show the former has an empty intersection with the complement of the latter and then reduce what follows form the $\triangle$ definition: X xor Y = (X\Y) ∪ (Y\X).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution contains a gap in the first step. You need to first show that $A\Delta B = (A\cup B)\backslash (A\cap B)$. Apply this to the LHS and use the absorption law and we are done. Note that the backslash symbol ($\backslash$) stands for the set minus ($-$) that you are familiar with.